# How to create a common processResources in Gradle for all source sets

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

For my build.gradle, I have three source sets:  main, test, and integrationTest.  The resource filtering I need to do for all three are the same, something like:

```
processResources {
   filesMatching(['abc.properties', 'xyz.properties']) {
       expand(version: "1.0",
             buildNumber: "123"
       )
   }
}
```

However, the above method just filters the main source set, for test and integrationTest I have to copy-and-paste the above method twice, calling one method processTestResources and the other one processIntegrationTestResources.

How can I create a single method that would be called for all three source sets?

Answer (score 0):

While I was hoping for some process*Resources that would hold for all SourceSets, I found I could just factor out the common logic into a separate function, as follows:

```
def standardProcessResources(obj) {
    obj.filesMatching(['abc.properties', 'xyz.properties']) {
        expand(version: "1.0",
            buildNumber: "123"
        )
    }
}
```

And then call that method from each of my process* tasks:

```
processResources {
    standardProcessResources(processResources)
}

processTestResources {
    standardProcessResources(processTestResources)
}

etc...
```